# Basic integrals from Calculus-Marsden $\int\frac{x^3+1}{x^2+1}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find the area under the graph of: $$\frac{x^3+1}{x^2+1}$$ on $[0,2]$. [Hint: Divide]

According to long division I got That the function is equal to $x-\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ but still have a problem with the integration because of $\frac{x}{x^2+1}$

Or maybe there’s some sort of typo in the book.

Could anyone give me a hint? Thanks.

Note: Answer is $2+\tan^{-1}2-(\ln5)/2$

Comment: You can use $u$-substitution too.

Comment: Consider $\log(1+x^2)$

Comment: Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{x}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\frac12\mathrm d(x^2+1)}{x^2+1}.$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Quite right. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn’t know I could do that.

Comment: I simply used differential calculus. It's a bit condensed, but  for me  it's enough.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\int\dfrac{x}{x^{2}+1}dx&=\int\dfrac{1}{x^{2}+1}d\left(\dfrac{1}{2}x^{2}\right)\\&=\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{1}{x^{2}+1}d(x^{2})\\&=\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{1}{x^{2}+1}d(x^{2}+1)\\&=\dfrac{1}{2}\log(x^{2}+1).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, I got the idea.